# NHibernate : TINYINT instead of geometry

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm working on a C# project using NHibernate, I use fluant-nhibernate with autoMapping :

```
        FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(databaseConfig)
            .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Entity>(mappingConfiguration).Conventions.Add<GeometryTypeConvention>()));
```

I have a classes with IGeometry properties, I have configured automapping with a self Convention type :

```
public class GeometryTypeConvention : IUserTypeConvention
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(p => p.Property.PropertyType == typeof (IGeometry));
    }

    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.CustomType(typeof(MsSql2008GeometryType));
    }
}
```

When I update the schema, the database is created but all Geometry properties in classes are set as TINYINT columns.

I've seen almost the same problem on http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/null-geometry-values-in-nhibernate-spatial-for-mssql2008, but the file MsSql2008GeometryType.cs I use is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I solved it this way (using geography instead of geometry, but it's very similar):

First (this step is optional), and because I was required to work with WGS84 coordinates, I created the following type:

```
public class Wgs84GeographyType : MsSql2008GeographyType
{
    protected override void SetDefaultSRID(GeoAPI.Geometries.IGeometry geometry)
    {
        geometry.SRID = 4326;
    }
}
```

Then I created a convention somehow similar to yours, but with the "CustomSqlType" method specified:

```
public class Wgs84GeographyTypeConvention : IPropertyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        if (typeof(IGeometry).IsAssignableFrom(instance.Property.PropertyType))
        {
            instance.CustomType(typeof(Wgs84GeographyType));
            instance.CustomSqlType("GEOGRAPHY");
        }
    }
}
```

Afterwards the schema generation should work without any issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `SpatialAuxiliaryDatabaseObject` in order to properly generate spatial related schema. Using Fluent NHibernate, this would look like:

```
    .ExposeConfiguration(
        cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(new SpatialAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(cfg));
            new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true);
        })
```

Also, set the dialect in the database configuration:

```
    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration
        .MsSql2008
        .Dialect(typeof (MsSql2008GeometryDialect).AssemblyQualifiedName)
```

Comment: You may also have to tell about using the type for SQL column in your mappings. I had to update it like this to make sure it outputs geography columns when using schema export. Property(x => x.Area, m => 
            {
                m.Type<Wgs84GeographyType>();
                m.Column(c => c.SqlType("geography"));
            });